# Python set variable from list to new value without pointing to new location

Tags: python

**Short version:**

If `x = [[True], [False]]`, and `n = x[0]`, is it possible/how do I set `x[0]` to an integer using only `n`?

**Long version:**

I'm trying to write a voxel type script which is using a lot of recursive lists, and I'm wondering if there's an alternative to `=` that won't overwrite the value of a variable set to an item in the list.

Take this as a basic example:

```
l = [0, [[[2], 0], 0], 0]
path = [1, 0, 0]

cur = l
for i in path
    cur = cur[i]

print cur
#[2]
```

Here's some examples of what can be done to update the list:

```
cur.append(3)
print l
#[None, [[[2, 3], 0], 0], 0]

cur[0] = 3
print l
#[0, [[[3], 0], 0], 0]
```

However, I'd like to be able to set the `[2]` value to something else, so that in the style of the above examples, `l` becomes `[0, [[3, 0], 0], 0]`. A bit like the below code, which obviously won't work:

```
cur = 3
print l
#[0, [[[2], 0], 0], 0]
```

I could follow the path down again just removing one level each time, but for 5 levels of recursion, that would be 120 calculations as opposed to just 5. I was thinking there might be some sort of function like `find_id(l).set_value(int, 3)` that's built in but not commonly used. Apologies if this has an answer already but I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: It seems like you're asking *"how can I mutate an immutable object"*, in which case the answer is, more or less inevitably, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is stop one short when processing the path, so rather than finding `cur`, you instead find `prev`.  You can then use the last index of `path` to modify `cur` within `prev`.  For example:

```
l = [0, [[[2], 0], 0], 0]
path = [1, 0, 0]

prev = l
for i in path[:-1]:
    prev = prev[i]

prev[path[-1]] = 3
print l
```

This prints:

```
[0, [[3, 0], 0], 0]
```

Of course, this only works if `path` is non-empty.